# Hibernate not returning the last record

Tags: hibernate, jsp, sql-server-2005

I have 10 records in SQL SERVER. I am trying to print 9 at a time for JSP Pagination . In the 1st page it is showing 9 records correctly, whereas in the 2nd page it is not showing any record:

```
    id      deptno  deptno2 deptno3 deptno4 deptno5 
    11      9   13           
    13      9   13  12       
    14      9                           
    20      9                           
    29      99  9   13  12   
    48      9                           
    52      9   13  12          
    55      9   13  12       
    60      9   12                  
    66      9
```

The HQL being genarated is as follows:

```
select top 9 this_.id_employee as id1_0_0_  this_.deptno as deptno0_0_, this_.deptno2 as deptno12_0_0_, this_.deptno3 as deptno13_0_0_, this_.deptno4 as deptno14_0_0_, this_.deptno5 as deptno15_0_0_  from hawkseye1.dbo.employee this_ where (this_.deptno=? or this_.deptno2=? or this_.deptno3=? or this_.deptno4=? or this_.deptno5=?) order by this_.name asc    

criteria.setFirstResult(startCounter); // This is 0 on 1st page, 10 on 2nd page
criteria.setMaxResults(9);
```

However, the list size is `9 first time` which is correct, but on the `second page` `it is 0, which should be 1`

ANy thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: what is the actual HQL that you have writtern. The generated query is an SQL and not an HQL.

Comment: oops mea culpa! I am using a criteria , and that is all I can see in logs, could you suggest where to look at

Comment: Hibernate Criteria is used. No need to write HQL.

Comment: @AbhijithNagarajan so any pointers where am I commiting mistake?

Comment: Are you sure you are setting the value as 9 for firstResult in the second iteration?

Comment: @ Abhijit , allow me to correct one thing, on the 1st page it is 0 , second it is 10

Comment: Not sure if anybody is going to answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the missing record mystery, it was glaring , I just had to fix the counter thing. Thanks all!